# Is it ok to use chat smiley somewhere in the txt while applying for a job via internet ?

Tags: software-industry, job-search, new-job

Today I applied for a job and while mentioning about my interest I pasted this smiley symbol `:)` in the section (It was an online form).

After submitting the form I am really concern about the symbol now. Will it going to affect my job prospects any how ? (post is for the s/w developer position).

Let me know if you need any more info regarding this.

Comment: Related question: [Does it hurt me to use smiley faces in correspondence with potential employers?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2324/316). I don't think it's an exact duplicate though since it's a bit more general about emoticons and general correspondence, while your question is relates to a more specific scenario.

Comment: @Rachel I already committed the crime ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No.**  It is definitely not acceptable to post emoticons, text abbreviations, or the like in communication between you and a potential employer, even if they do it first.  It is unprofessional and makes you look juvenile.

This is similar to you walking into an interview without wearing a suit.  Even if the person interviewing you is in shorts, flip-flops, and a t-shirt, you still need to act professionally and give off vibes that you are competent enough to understand how to act in a given situation.

At the end of the day, I don't think that one thing alone will destroy your chances at getting a job, but it definitely didn't help.

Comment: So do i thought the same :(

Comment: If they have to choose between you and another equal developer, it may be that thing that sets you two apart (you not in a good way).

Comment: Careful with the absolutes. For example, if you walk into a technical interview at Apple with a suit on, you will probably dinged for it since you clearly didn't do your homework. I do agree however with your recommendation, emoticons are third date material at best.

Comment: I agree that using emoticons and textspeak in a job application is a bad idea - but like Hilmar I think you're going too hard with the absolutes. It's a bad idea because it's *more likely* to hurt you than help you. It's certainly not *guaranteed* to hurt you, and it *might* possibly help. You don't know the personality of the person on the receiving end of the application - they may warm to you as a result of your informality.